# "Maybe I have colored it too much"

Tags: popular-refrains

Is that understandable in English? Or maybe there is a better way to illustrate what I want to say.

What I want to say is that maybe I have exaggerated.

For example,

> God is always good.

He kind of committed genocide with the big flood. So he's not always good but most of the time likes everybody.

Comment: Nota bene I'm an atheist, but I think the flood was supposed to be justified by a story. Genocide is a rather new idea.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I'm not saying that he did something wrong with the flood, but I'm saying that it was not 100% good. So the person that says he's always good has exaggerated.

Comment: "kinda of" is very poor grammar, by the way... Kinda = _Kind of_

Comment: @mplungjan poor grammar or being cool? i think its cool to say kinda or kindda.

Comment: Fer sure. Jus' reckon youd git sum kinda flack fer writin' kinda hear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"maybe I have exaggerated" is clear to me. "maybe I have colored it too much" is not.

When the adjective colorful is applied to English text it is usually understood to mean that the text uses vivid and probably idiosyncratic metaphor or simile. The sentence "God is always good" isn't one I would regard as particularly colorful.

> 'I don't like your manner' Kingsley said in a voice you could have cracked a brazil nut on. 'That's all right,' I said, 'I'm not selling it.'

Sometimes colorful is used to mean "contains expletives". If you had said "God is never a ****", I would agree you had "colored it too much".

If the part you are asking about is the not the part you quoted but the part about genocide, then I would agree that many might regard that as overly colorful, depending on context and your objective.

Comment: thx, in my language colored means exaggerated. I just wanted to check that out :)